# Trying to create a Sass mixin that writes a long list of semantic icon names appending a uniquely iterated number

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Trying to create a Sass mixin that writes a  long list of semantic icon names appending a uniquely iterated number.

**Chunk of Sass**

```
$icon-name: pencil trash calendar;
$icon-num: length($icon-name);


@for $i from 1 through $icon-num {
    $class-slug: test-icon !default;
    .#{$class-slug}-#{$icon-name}-#{$icon-num} {
        content: $i;
    }
}
```

**RESULT:::::::::::::::::**

```
.test-icon-pencil trash calendar-3 {
  content: 1;
}
.test-icon-pencil trash calendar-3 {
  content: 2;
}
.test-icon-pencil trash calendar-3 {
  content: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Figured it out - $collection is like a Sass array:**

```
$collection: (pencil, trash, calendar);
$icon-num: length($collection);
$class-slug: test-icon !default;

@for $i from 0 to $icon-num {

    $this-name: nth($collection, $i+1);
    .#{$class-slug}-#{$this-name} {
        content: $i;
    }
}
```

**Output renders:**

```
.test-icon-pencil {
  content: 0;
}
.test-icon-trash {
  content: 1;
}
.test-icon-calendar {
  content: 2;
}
```